# Numerical moments of a multivariate Poisson Log-normal posterior

Tags: bayesian, poisson-distribution, lognormal-distribution, moments, numerical-integration

I have a log-density of the form:
$$P(\mathbf{x}) \propto \exp\left( - \mathbf{b}^{\top} e^{ \mathbf{x} } - \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^{\top}A\mathbf{x} \right)$$
where $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix. Here $\mathbf x, \mathbf b \in\mathbb{R}^N$ are vectors in $N$ dimensions, and $A$ is $N\times N$. The components of $\mathbf b$ are all non-negative. Note that $e^\mathbf x$ here denotes component-wise exponentiation.

In the particular application I have in mind, $N=3$. Also, the components of $\mathbf b$ can be large. For more context, $P(\mathbf x)$ arises as the posterior of log-normally distributed rates under observed Poisson counts (i.e., the multivariate Poisson-log normal distribution).

I need to evaluate **numerically** (I don't think there are analytical expressions for this) the first and second moments of $\mathbf x$, that is,
$$
\langle \mathbf x\rangle, \quad 
\langle \mathbf x\mathbf x^\top\rangle, \quad
\operatorname{cov}(\mathbf x), \quad
$$
all under $P(\mathbf x)$.

I have tried sampling (MALA, HMC, ...) but it is difficult to get these to converge. I am also looking into numerical integration methods.

Some nice properties of the integrand, is that $\log P(\mathbf x)$ is a concave function of $\mathbf x$ and therefore has a single maximum, that is easy to locate (*e.g.* using Newton optimization).

Any suggestions?

Comment: A specific example for $N=3$ would be helpful.

Comment: I have edited the question to remove $\mathbf u$, since it can be absorbed in the other parameters. @JimB an example would amount to giving 3+3+6 parameter values in total. Why would that help?

Comment: It would help in that it would demonstrate maybe why you're having convergence issues and it would be essential to any numerical integration.  You say some vectors have large norms and large is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Simplified a bit more ...

Comment: I take it that all $b_i>0$.  If so the factor $\exp(-\mathbf{b}^T e^\mathbf{x})\le 1$ and can can be used the acceptance probability in a rejection sampler with a zero-mean Guassian proposal with precision matrix $A$.  I think the overall acceptance rate will be about $1/2^N$.

Comment: Yes, $b_i \ge 0$ (I forgot to mention that). But if the $b_i$ are large, the acceptance probabilities will be quite small, right? @JarleTufto

Comment: No, you can rewrite the factor as follows
$$
\begin{align}
\exp(-\mathbf{b}^T e^\mathbf{x})
&=\exp(-\sum_{i=1}^N b_ie^{x_i}))
\\&=\prod_{i=1}^N\exp(-b_ie^{x_i}))
\\&=\prod_{i=1}^N\exp(-e^{x_i\ln b_i }))
\\&=\prod_{i=1}^N(1-\operatorname{cloglog}^{-1}(x_i\ln b_i ))
\end{align}
$$
i.e. as  product of componentwise inverse cloglogs.  Each factor in this product will remove about half of the mass in the acceptance step, at least, if $A$ is approximately diagonal.

Comment: What if $A$ is far from diagonal?

Comment: It would depend on the correlations of the proposal.  If they are mostly positive I think this would work unless of course $N$ is large.

Comment: Have you tried just metropolis within Gibbs? It's a lot sturdier than the gradient-based approaches you have reported trying, or at least, such is the case with the popular implementations of each.

Comment: @JohnMadden Can you be a bit more explicit, what do you mean by "metropolis within Gibbs" ?

Comment: You go through your variables one by one. For each variable, you sample from its posterior conditional distribution given all the others using Metropolis(-Hastings). This is the most common "all-purpose" MCMC algo, and it's easy to overlook with the flashier alternatives these days.

Comment: @JohnMadden How do I know if the Gibbs sampling has converged?

Comment: poke around this site for more (that's like, a whole 'nother question), but in brief, you want your trace plots to look like fuzzy caterpillars.